# Does next() look for a __pairs metamethod?

Tags: lua, metatable, meta-method

In general, the syntax:

```
for k, v in pairs(t) do
   ....
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
for k, v in next, t do
    ....
end
```

But what if `t` has a `__pairs` metamethod?  Will the standard `next()` function check for this?  If not, isn't it better to *always* use `pairs` when iterating over tables, and never call `next()` directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `next()` doesn't check for `__pairs`. [The manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next) doesn't say so.

It can be double confirmed from the related source code, compare [`luaB_pairs`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lbaselib.c.html#luaB_pairs) and [`luaB_next`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lbaselib.c.html#luaB_next).

There might be times when you *don't* want to check for `__pairs` metamethod, so why say *always* use `pairs` over `next`?